# Filtering django rest framework query set using a custom filter backend

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm having problems with filtering the query set. Here is a simplified data model:

```
Entry
- id
- broadcast_groups

User
- id
- groups
```

So an entry can be broadcasted (shared) in a group. I have a `GET /entries/` endpoint that returns entry objects.

I want to filter a query set to return entries that fulfill following requirements:

- are not broadcasted in any group **OR**
- are broadcasted in groups the user is member of.

I'm scratching my head how to achieve this. I figured that maybe writing a custom `FilterBackend` is a good idea. Here is what I have so far:

```
class CanViewPublicOrGroupMemberEntriesFilterBackend(filters.BaseFilterBackend):

    def filter_queryset(self, request, queryset, view):
        user = request.user
        return queryset.filter(broadcast_groups__in=user.groups.all())
```

However, this does not yield results that I am expecting. What would be a `filter()` syntax to achieve such filtering? Or maybe I'm approaching the problem from the wrong side?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for Q objects https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects

```
class CanViewPublicOrGroupMemberEntriesFilterBackend(filters.BaseFilterBackend):
    def filter_queryset(self, request, queryset, view):
        user = request.user
        return queryset.filter(
            Q(broadcast_groups__in=user.groups.all()) |
            Q(broadcast_groups__isnull=True)
        )
```

Comment: This is so simple!